# Why does the python Cassandra driver fail when declared as a class field?

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm currently working with a server process that is meant to connect to a Cassandra database and forward information to it. This process is written as a class, and my goal is to create a single Cassandra session for this class that it can use to send the information. However, I'm running into a problem; when I create a Cassandra session in the classes **init** method, and then later try to use the session in another method, I get the following error:
`errors={}, last_host=<server IP address>`. I can currently get around this problem by creating a new Cassandra session each time the method is called, but this is obviously not a good way to go about this. So, how can I make a Cassandra session that I can use consistently throughout the class?

This code does NOT work:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from multiprocessing import Process
class DataProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self):

        super(DataProcess,self).__init__()

        # Do a few other irrelevant things ...

        # Set up the Cassandra connection
        self.cluster = Cluster(contact_points=[CASSANDRA_IP])
        self.session = self.cluster.connect('some keyspace')
        print "Connected to cassandra."

    def callback(self,ch,method,props,body):
        prepared_statement = self.session.prepare("Some CQL statement...")
        bound_statement = prepared_statement.bind(some values)
        self.session.execute(bound_statement)

Output:
"Connected to cassandra."
errors={}, last_host=<server IP address>
```

This code DOES work, but it's a silly way to do it:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from multiprocessing import Process
class DataProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self):

        super(DataProcess,self).__init__()

        # Do a few irrelevant things ...


    def callback(self,ch,method,props,body):
        # Set up the Cassandra connection
        cluster = Cluster(contact_points=[CASSANDRA_IP])
        session = cluster.connect('some keyspace')
        prepared_statement = session.prepare("Some CQL statement...")
        bound_statement = prepared_statement.bind(some values)
        session.execute(bound_statement)
```

Other relevant info:

Using python cassandra-driver version 2.5.1

Cassandra database version 2.1.8

EDIT: ANSWER
The following code solved the issue:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from multiprocessing import Process
class DataProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self):

        super(DataProcess,self).__init__()
        self.cluster = None
        self.session = None
        # Do a few irrelevant things ...


    def callback(self,ch,method,props,body):
        # Set up the Cassandra connection
        cluster = Cluster(contact_points=[CASSANDRA_IP])
        session = cluster.connect('some keyspace')
        prepared_statement = session.prepare("Some CQL statement...")
        bound_statement = prepared_statement.bind(some values)
        session.execute(bound_statement)

    def run(self):
        self.cluster = Cluster(contact_points=[CASSANDRA_IP])
        self.session = self.cluster.connect('some keyspace')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you creating your cluster and sessions before the fork? That could cause issues like what you are seeing. There is an amazing writeup of how to distribute work using pools using the python driver here [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-python-driver-multiprocessing-example-for-improved-bulk-data-throughput). This will likely be exactly what you are looking for.

If it's not please leave more context on how you are running your process, as it's tough to reproduce without knowing your process lifecycle.

Comment: Ah, that was it. I just moved the code over to the run() method for the process. Nice catch, thanks!